# How to delete folder/files from Databricks mnt directory

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am running Databricks Community Edition and I would like to delete files from the following mnt directory

`/mnt/driver-daemon/jars`

I run the dbutils command:

`dbutils.fs.rm('/mnt/driver-daemon/jars/', True)`

However, when I run the command I get the following message (which basically means the folder hasn't been deleted)

`Out[1]: False`

Can someone let me know where I going wrong?
Ideally, I would like to delete all the files in the jars folder, however, if someone could just help showing how to delete the folder, that will suffice.

Comment: I was  able to run `dbutils.fs.rm` just fine. What happens if you run `%fs rm -r /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/`?

Comment: %fs rm -r /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/ worked. cheers

Comment: @DavidGibson Would you like you post that as an answer so OP can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Hi @DavidGibson, yes I would like to have it posted as an answer. I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: Great, glad to help! And yes I just re-posted as an answer.

Comment: @Carltonp you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `dbutils.fs.rm()` does not work you can always use the the `%fs` FileSystem magic commands. To remove a director you can use the following.

```sh
%fs rm -r /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/
```

where

- `%fs` magic command to use **dbutils**
- `rm` remove command
- `-r` recursive flag to delete a directory and all its contents
- `/mnt/driver-daemon/jars/` path to directory

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to local `/mnt/driver-daemon/jars` ,it wouldn't be good idea to remove it since it is symlink to `/databricks/jars` directory and would impact driver functionality. The path `/mnt/driver-daemon/jars/` resolves to `dbfs:/mnt/driver-daemon/jars/` whose equivalent local file system directory `/dbfs/mnt/driver-daemon/jars`. If you want to delete local file system directories, you can prefix `file:` schema before the path (like `file:/tmp/deleteme`) with dbutils commands.

```
 %sh ls -ltrh /dbfs/mnt/driver-daemon/jars /mnt/driver-daemon/jars 
      ls: cannot access '/dbfs/mnt/driver-daemon/jars': No such file or directory
      lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul  2 23:14 /mnt/driver-daemon/jars -> /databricks/jars
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can delete folder/files or folder with underline directories and file by using following command.**

dbutils.fs.rm("/Path/", recurse=True)

*use your path like "/FileStore/Directory1/File1.txt"